# How do I calculate the angle to place rectangles side by side around a circumference?

Tags: circles, rectangles

I have a circle with radius $r$ and several rectangular objects. All rectangles have the same sides $a$ and $b$ (although the side $a$ may be different from side $b$). I would like to place the rectangles centered on the circumference, all the way around, so they don't overlap. Suppose I place the first rectangle (blue) at angel 0.

I want to place the next rectangle (green) side by side without overlapping, then the gray and so on...
How do I calculate the angle $\alpha$ for each rectangle?

[image: Rectangles on a circumference]

I don't have any issues with placing the rectangle centered on the circumference, it is the angel $\alpha$ for each rectangle that is my problem to calculate.

If things get more simple we can assume quadrants ($a$=$b$) instead of rectangles and even use the worst case as the common angle for all rectangles...

I'm aware of that there might be a gap in the end (as shown in the picture between blue and gray) and I intend to spread this gap evenly between all rectangles.

**EDIT**
Okay I sort of came up with one dirty solution where I use the same angle for all quadrants.
If I tilt the quadrat 45 degree (worst case), the diagonal will form a chord on the circumference. I know the radius so from this I can calculate the occupied arc angle.

$H=\sqrt{b^2*2}$
$\alpha = 2*\arcsin{(\frac{H}{2*r}})$

But I'm still looking forward to a "real" solution as the first picture shows...
[image]

Comment: Hmm... You realize the rectangles may or may not make it all the way around the circle.

Comment: For just the two, it appears that $a$ doesn't matter, so $\alpha = asin(\frac{b}{r})$

Comment: @rubberchicken. Yes I know, and this will be taken care of in another stage. I will try out your formula...

Comment: If $b$ is large enough to take the top of the first rectangle outside the circle, you're already finished. Are their criteria for $b$? This doesn't seem a fully well defined question as it stands.

Comment: @rubberchicken. I have tried your suggestion and they start to overlap more and more when I get closer to a 45 degree angle.

Comment: $\alpha$ changes with each rectangle being placed - see @David's answer. My comment applied only to the two in the picture.

Answer (score 2):

Call your initial rectangle number $0$, the next number $1$ and so on.  Sooner or later you are going to hit the top of the circle and not be able to place another rectangle on top of the previous one, but until that happens, the centre of rectangle $k$ will have $y$ coordinate $kb$, distance from the origin $r$, so the angle above the horizontal will be
$$\sin^{-1}\frac{kb}{r}\ .$$

Comment: Not really sure I follow you here, but I will make a try. Thankyou every one for the quick help. I will try this out immediately...

Comment: Just look at your diagram.  The vertical distance of the centre of the green rectangle above the horizontal axis is $\frac{1}{2}\!b\,$ (inside the blue rectangle) plus $\frac{1}{2}\!b\,$ (inside the green rectangle), total $b$.  For the next rectangle it would go up by the same again, total $2b$, and so on.

Comment: A really stupid question, but I'm far from a mathematician, $sin^{-1}$ is the same as $asin$ aka $arcsin$? I'm writing in C++ so I need to find the right math functions :P

Comment: Yes, same thing.

Comment: I have tried your solution and I get it to work quite well up to 90 degree angle, then the radian gets to big for the ArcSin() function (it only accept values between -1 and 1). I use this formula `ArcSin( ( (k*b) / r) -1)` Is it possible to get all 4 quadrants into the same formula?

Comment: Yes, the formula will break down when the problem stops working - you can't keep on stacking rectangles on top of each other forever as you will go past the top of the circle.  What do you do then - maybe place the rectangle beside the previous one instead of above?  Perhaps you could edit your original question to give us some more information here.

Comment: Thank you for your patient. I have updated the question and title. I hope it is more clear now what I need...

Comment: ...only now it's more difficult ;-)  Will see what I can do but it will probably have to wait till tomorrow.

Comment: Well, I'm reading all the trigonometry I can find to refresh my school math. I'm currently trying to use the worst case where the square occupy most space at 45 degree. The square diagonal forms  a chord and from that I can calculate the arc length and then divide the circle by that. This would result in the angle increment I need for each rectangle around the circle... or maybe I'm out on deep water here.. I'm looking forward to see what you are coming up with =)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13011/discussion-between-david-and-max-kielland)